# How to prevent Jenkins autostart on startup Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: ubuntu, jenkins, startup

I am experimenting with Docker. When I install containers, they conflicts to my existing Jenkins port. I am not using Jenkins at this case. How to prevent Jenkins to run on start-up.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
sudo systemctl disable jenkins.service
```

This command will prevent systemd from starting jenkins the next time you reboot.

To enable autostart again, use:

```
sudo systemctl enable jenkins.service
```

Answer (score 4):

On Ubuntu in the `/etc/rc.local` you could delete `/etc/init.d/jenkins start`

Another idea could be to go through chkconfig, and remove Jenkins:

```
chkconfig --del jenkins
```